how to make the spring boot force to use specify profile(disable others)
I am using intellij idea 2023.1.1 to do a unit test with spring boot using JDK21, after I added the profile annotion in the test class:
@ActiveProfiles("test")

the log still show there contains 2 active profiles dev, test. I have tried to check the project application.yaml, the Intellij Idea environment variable, the startup command when run the unit test log output, and did not found the dev profile setting. Now I only want to use the test as the active profile. what should I do? is it possible to force override the dev active profile?

One suggestion would be to check the test profile. Does that profile use dev maybe?
Check the application-test file in both src/test/resources/ and src/main/resources (if it exists there) and verify it doesn't use the default.
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev

I hope that helps.
Not able to leave a comment due to lack of reputation.
